# I've locked a field but can't even put data in the first place

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Here is my form:

[image]

I want to lock the dateOpened once the user selects a date. However, when I select a date, it doesn't appear in the box when it is "locked" in the property panel. I was wondering if there is a simple trick to circumvent that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `Locked` property affects the date picker as well.

You should set `Locked = False` in the property sheet, and in the `AfterUpdate` event procedure of the date control:

```
Me!dateOpened.Locked = True
```

If the user can add new records with this form without it being closed and reopened, you must set `.Locked = False` in that case.